# Setting $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is Eclipse PHP Neon

Tags: php, eclipse

This line

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/api/database/databaseCommon.php');
```

gives the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/api/common/RequireCommonStuff.php' (include_path='
```

I am testing on `localhost`, using Xampp and can't find the configuration option in Eclipse to set `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to `localhost` or its path on my harddrive.

Comment: What do you have DOCUMENT_ROOT specified as in your server configuration file?

Comment: The root folder of my Eclipse project

Comment: It doesn't seem to be registering it. Did you restart your apache after changing the value?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have undefined document root. You have to follow apache configuration, check your vHost definition.